# Error Undefined offset: 1, como solucionarlo?

Tags: php, laravel, array, rutas

La situación es la siguiente, tengo un array guardado en la DB en json. El mismo contiene rutas de imagenes. Lo que estoy buscando es poder acceder a lo distintos valores de este array.

```
$array_fotos = json_decode($perro->img,true);
              var_dump($array_fotos);
```

Esto me devuelve el array de la siguiente manera:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "pelaje.jpg" [1]=> string(8) "pelo.jpg" [2]=> string(14) "perro-raro.jpg" }
```

Cuando quiero ingresar al valor 0, no hay problema:

```
$foto_uno = $array_fotos[0];
var_dump($foto_uno);
```

Me devuelve:

```
string(10) "pelaje.jpg"
```

Pero cuando intento hacer lo mismo con la posición 1 del array,de la misma manera con la cual ingrese a la posicion 0 del array me salta el siguiente error.

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Gracias de antemano y perdón si estoy preguntando algo obvio, soy nuevo.

Comment: ese error aparece por que no encuentra ningún valor en dicha posición, seguro que siempre te esta regresando esas 3 posiciones?

Comment: Si, siempre. Ademas con el valor 0 no tengo problema, me ocurre con el 1 en adelante

Comment: Acabé de realizar una prueba exactamente igual y me funciona perfectamente.